# Lemma 1.7 in chapter 5 in Ergodic Theorems by Ulrich Krengel.

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The lemma is on page 181.

Here's the lemma and its proof:
[image]

I don't understand how did they get:

$$\lim | S^{n_k+1}f(\omega)|\leq \gamma (\alpha - \epsilon)+(1-\gamma)\alpha$$

The term that is confusing is $\gamma (\alpha - \epsilon)$, I mean I understand why $\alpha - \epsilon$, but not why times $\gamma$.

I mean $P(\omega_k , F ) \geq \gamma$, and not less than or equal $\gamma$.

Comment: In the proof from the screenshot, there's the line "Observe that $P(\omega_k,F^c)\leq 1-\gamma$". In your question, you write "$P(\omega_k,F) \geq \gamma$". Those two statements are consistent. Are you aware of this? Or is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Yes, this line is consistent. my question is on $|\lim S^{n_k+1}f(\omega)|$, it seems they use $\lim |S^{n_k+1}f(\omega)| \leq \lim|S^{n_k}f(\eta)|_{\eta \in F} P(\omega_k,F) + \lim |S^{n_k}f(\eta)|_{eta \in F^c} P(\omega_k, F^c) $, but they don't have an upper estimate on P(\omega, F), only lower estimate; that's my problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not have this book so what I know is the part of the book you showed in your question. So sorry for any misunderstanding. I think the reason is the following.

From (1.3) we know that $$|S^{n_k+1}f(\omega)| \leq \max_{\eta \in F}|S^{n_k}f(\eta)| P(\omega_k,F) + \max_{\eta \in F^c}  |S^{n_k}f(\eta)|P(\omega_k, F^c).$$ Note that for any $\delta>0$, we can find $k$ such that  $\max_{\eta \in F}|S^{n_k}f(\eta)| \leq \alpha-\epsilon+\delta$ and that $\max_{\eta \in F^c}|S^{n_k}f(\eta)| \leq \alpha+\delta$ so $$|S^{n_k+1}f(\omega)| \leq (\alpha-\epsilon+\delta) P(\omega_k,F) + (\alpha+\delta)P(\omega_k, F^c).\\ \leq \alpha+\delta-\epsilon P(\omega_k,F)\leq \alpha+\delta-\epsilon\gamma.$$ Then let $k\to 0$ so that $\delta\to 0$ we have the inequality.