# A polynomial equality for the square of a self-adjoint positive contraction in $L^2$ -- from Krengel's book Ergodic theorems

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Another mystery from Ulrich Krengel's textbook - Ergodic Theorems ([first mystery](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064870/lemma-1-7-in-chapter-5-in-ergodic-theorems-by-ulrich-krengel)). This time it's from page 190, in the proof of theorem 2.7.

He takes $P=T^2$, where $T$ is a self-adjoint positive contraction in $L^2$, and argues that it's easy to check that:

$$P^n f - A_{n+1}(P) f = (n+1)^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n k(P^k - P^{k-1})f$$

where $A_{n+1}(P) f = (n+1)^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^n P^k f$.

I only get that:

$$\frac{n}{n+1}P^n f -(n+1)^{-1} f -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n+1)^{-1}P^k f$$

Can someone show me how did he get this sum above?

Comment: People seeing this question do not necessarily know your other questions (you asked the "first mystery" from Krengel's book about 3 weeks ago), so stylistically it'd be good to keep the question self-contained in the writing style by not saying "Another mystery..." or "This time...". Imagine a complete stranger came up to you and said "Oh, I have a follow-up question."

Comment: Ok, thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from where you get and calling $x_k=P^kf$, one must show that $$nx_n-x_0 -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k=\sum_{k=1}^n k(x_k - x_{k-1}).$$
This is purely algebraic. For example, the RHS is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n kx_k -\sum_{k=1}^n k x_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n kx_k -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1) x_{k}=nx_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx_k -x_0-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1) x_{k},$$ that is, $$nx_n-x_0-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_{k}=(n+1)x_n-\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_{k},$$ as desired.